# when i click button to other pages it shows my landing page with no css

Tags: php, model-view-controller, nav

So when i open my code on localhost/mframe the top of the project it looks like this
[landing page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYHMr.jpg)

from here if i click the home button which should show the exact same page it goes to the url http://localhost/mframe/pages/index and shows the headers and nav for the landing page but it isnt using the css and looks like this
[home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toMZh.png)

then if i click the auction button it goes to the url http://localhost/mframe/pages/auction which shows the same page as above the landing page without css when it should just show the nav as thats been called in as required

finally my about page if i click that it opens a blank white page when it should open the page with the nav top right using the css but its just blank like this
[about page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeCD2.png)

my code is set up with mvc php my code is below

config.php class

```
<?php
//Database params
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); //Add your db host
define('DB_USER', 'root'); // Add your DB root
define('DB_PASS', ''); //Add your DB pass
define('DB_NAME', 'auctionsystem'); //Add your DB Name

    //APPROOT
    define('APPROOT',  dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));

    //URLROOT (Dynamic links)
    define('URLROOT', 'http://localhost/mframe');

    //site name
    define('SITENAME', 'Auction System');
```

my head.php

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta htttp-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><?php echo SITENAME; ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

my navigation.php

```
<nav class="top-nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/pages/index">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/pages/about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/pages/auction">Auction Items</a>
        </li>
        <li class="btn-login">
            <a href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/users/login">Login/Signup</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

auction/about page code identical yet different when i open them up

```
<?php
require APPROOT . '/views/includes/head.php';
?>
<div class="navbar">
    <?php
    require APPROOT . '/views/includes/navigation.php';
    ?>
</div>
```

and index.php code

```
<?php
    require APPROOT . '/views/includes/head.php';
?>

    <div id="section-landing">
        <?php
        require APPROOT . '/views/includes/navigation.php';
        ?>
        <div class="wrapper-landing">
            <div>
                <h1>One Man crappy software</h1>
                <h2>is another mans job</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

login.php code

```
<?php
require APPROOT . '/views/includes/head.php';
?>
<div class="navbar">
    <?php
    require APPROOT . '/views/includes/navigation.php';
    ?>
</div>
    <div class="container-login">
        <div class="wrapper-login">
            <h2>Sign in</h2>

            <form action="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/users/login" method="POST">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username *" name="username">
                <span class="invalidFeedback">
                   <?php echo $data['usernameError']; ?>
                </span>

                <input type="password" placeholder="Password *" name="password">
                <span class="invalidFeedback">
                   <?php echo $data['passwordError']; ?>
                </span>

                <button id="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
                    Submit
                </button>
                <p class="options">Not registered yet? <a href="<?php echo URLROOT;?>/users/register">Create an account!</a> </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

so i need to know why i have no css on any of the other pages why the about and auction page load up different despite having the same code and also why when i click the home button it doesnt show the same landing page

Comment: What do your `href`s look like? Most likely you link to `login` instead of `/login`

Comment: <nav class="top-nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/pages/index">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/pages/about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/pages/auction">Auction Items</a>
        </li>
        <li class="btn-login">
            <a href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/users/login">Login/Signup</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

Comment: that is my navigation.php class i believe the issue with my url and clicking must be something to do with the way ive set up my mvc cos it just repeates localhost full path for each click

Comment: @tester Edit your code into your question. It's unreadable in the comments.

Comment: added the code i have fixed the button links however if you read my response to the answer its still not working as it should

Comment: Change `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>` to <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css"/> to make your styles work.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 types of HTML Redirect Links.

Absolute and Relative.

Absolute is:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/page1.html">Link</a>
```

Relative link is:

```
<a href="page.html">Link</a>
```

You are using absolute link without `https://` prefix. So it expect a relative link and adding absolute link to your domain link.
You can add `http://` or `https://` prefix to fix it.

Comment: done that to my url root the buttons work semi but when i click home button it loads the landing page without css unlike when i search the url for it it loads with css

Comment: the landing page with css has this url http://localhost/mframe/ while when i click the homepage it takes me to http://localhost/mframe/pages/index which has no css but the same headers etc

Comment: and when i click the auction site it takes me to http://localhost/mframe/pages/auction but it shows the headers for home page despite the auction.php file having nothing but require head and nav so it should be a blank page with a nav bar

Comment: don't add the 'pages/index' to homepage button.

Comment: auction link is correct. that's another question. you can ask another question for that and share code with it.

Comment: what as for why it shows landing page instead of the auction and why it has no css?

Comment: problem is i need to wait 90 mins lol do you have any ideas?

Comment: please edit your question and add the pages/auction page code.

Comment: i have edited full question with code and screenshots of issues